# Sorting an array numerically

Tags: arrays, sorting, printing

What would be the best way to sort an array of numbers into ascending order without using any built in java.  This is what I have which I know will not work, my main question is how would you check the next variable of the array to see if it's less than that one then print the array in that order?

```
for (int = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) { 
    if (newArray[i] < newArray[i+]) {
        newArray[i] = newArray[i+]
    } else {
        return newArray[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you give "sorting algorithms" a quick google, you'll find plenty of different methods of sorting.

Comment: By "best" do you mean fastest (which probably would be counting / radix sort) or reasonably fast and simple (quick sort, heap sort, merge sort, ... ).